# Поиск, удаление и добавление класса в список классов

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, классы

Есть элемент `<a class="firstClass secondClass thirdClass">Рабочий элемент</a>`. При наведении мыши на этот элемент

1. должен проверяться класс thirdClass - присутствует ли этот класс в списке классов;
2. если не присутствует, то должен добавляться в список классов

Также хочу знать как удалять класс из списка классов. (все эти действия должны производиться в javascript и jquery)

3. Каким образом можно реализовать следующую логику

При наведении курсора мыши на пункт меню (hover) текст пункта меню становится жирным (при этом добавляется класс `.menulistitem_selected`), а при покидании курсора мыши текст пункта меню становится обычным (удаляется класс `.menulistitem_selected`)? Я задал 3-й вопрос, потому что не уверен нужен ли `toggle` (такое ощущение, что нужен поиск по списку классов).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('a');

elements.forEach((element) =>
{
  element.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) =>
  {
    event.target.classList.add('thirdClass');
  });
});
```

```css
a.thirdClass::after
{
  content: "(с классом thirdClass)"
}
```

```html
<a class="firstClass secondClass thirdClass">Рабочий элемент</a><br>
<a class="firstClass secondClass">Рабочий элемент</a>
```

Следующая задача

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

items.forEach((item) =>
{
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) =>
    {
        event.target.classList.add('menulistitem_selected');
    });

    item.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) =>
    {
        event.target.classList.remove('menulistitem_selected');
    });
});
```

```css
.menulistitem_selected
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Menu item 1</li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
    <li>Menu item 3</li>
    <li>Menu item 4</li>
    <li>Menu item 5</li>
    <li>Menu item 6</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Информация**

Добавить класс:

```js
Element.classList.add('thirdClass');
```

Или же несколько:

```js
Element.classList.add('thirdClass', 'secondClass');
```

---

Удалить класс:

```js
Element.classList.remove('thirdClass');
```

Или же несколько:

```js
Element.classList.remove('thirdClass', 'secondClass');
```

---

Переключить класс (то есть.. Если у элемента был такой класс - он убирается, если не было - добавляется).

```js
Element.classList.toggle('thirdClass');
```

Так же можно указать `boolean` значение, вторым параметром, что будет значить.. При true - всегда добавлять класс, при false - всегда убирать (если их нету или они есть).

```js
Element.classList.toggle('thirdClass', true);
```

Comment: я понятно прояснил вопрос?

Comment: Вроде да. Toggle в данном случае я думаю не нужен.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: @megafrontprogrammer, если ответ решает ваш вопрос - отметьте его правильным (галочка слева от ответа).